# Redirect the servlet request to another servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web

In our app for all the notification we trigger through mail.

All the templates have non sso link 
>/Userlogin?param1=param2value&param2=param2value">Link to access app

I need to modify this link in all templates  to

>/Userloginsso?param1=param2value&param2=param2value">Link to access app

Since there are many templates and takes lot of manual effort, is there any way we can redirect the request of Userlogin to Userloginsso. Any configuration that we can do in web.xml ?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you? if yes, mark the one that worked for you as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have a mapping for Userlogin in web.xml as below:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Userlogin</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>com.something.Userlogin</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Userlogin</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/Userlogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Modify existing mapping to :

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Userloginsso</servlet-name>
         <servlet-path>com.something.Userloginsso</servlet-path>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Userloginsso</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/Userlogin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now all calls to Userlogin will be redirected to Userloginsso servlet.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple redirect in your UserLogin servlet with the following:

```
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String param1 = request.getParameter ("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter ("param2");
    // other parameters 

    // Build the new url: if too much parameters, prefer using a StringBuilder over String concatenation for better performances 
    String baseUrl = request.getContextPath () + "/Userloginsso?param1=" + param1 + "&param2=" + param2;

    String encodedUrl = response.encodeRedirectURL (baseUrl);

    response.sendRedirect (encodedUrl);
}
```

Comment: Add a trip through `response.encodeRedirectURL` and you'll get an up-vote from me :)

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thanks for the improvement suggestion! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you could use a filter [example here](https://www.journaldev.com/1933/java-servlet-filter-example-tutorial) get the url and foward it somplace else in your app. Or and url rewrite library such us [this one](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

If you still want a servlet you could use a ProxyServlet. There are already many good implementations.

Examples:

[Complex proxy servlet with all features](https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet)

[Simple proxy servlet, limited features](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/simple-proxy-servlet-slow-requests)